# Build Failed with an Exception \\ Gradle Problem

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to build the default app ("Hello World") in Android Studio, and I really don't how do I fix this problem:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not update C:\Users\silveira\.gradle\caches\6.1.1\file-changes\last-build.bin
> C:\Users\silveira\.gradle\caches\6.1.1\file-changes\last-build.bin (Acess denied)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Did you try to run the compile with the stated options?